# Bottom curve on hero image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a curve on the bottom of my hero image but it's hard to get it the way I want it. If anyone has any suggestions it would be highly appreciated.

What I am trying to get
[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: lightblue;
}

div#hero {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 50vh;
  background-image: url('https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/soap-bubble-1958650_960_720.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 130% 600px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 130% 600px;
  margin-left: -2em;
  padding-right: 4em;
}

.button {
  height: 60px;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: -25px auto;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id="hero"></div>
```

Comment: Can you post a link to a design you are trying to realize? Depending on that, the answer will vary.

Comment: yes sorry i forgot to add it. coming up

Answer (score 1):

It seems like reducing the vertical scale and expanding the horizontal gets you closer like so:

```
border-bottom-left-radius: 150% 200px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 150% 200px;
```

An alternative may be to use `clip-path` to customize a shape to form. Modify your css to:

```
#hero {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 50vh;
  background-image: url('https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/soap-bubble-1958650_960_720.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 85%, 50% 100%, 100% 85%, 100% 0%);
  margin-left: -2em;
  padding-right: 4em;
}
```

The only downside is that IE/edge aren't supported but most others are (Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Mobile)

I think this is a great resource on the subject and provides some good examples.

http://karenmenezes.com/shapes-polygon/